# A basic question about eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose a symmetric matrix $A$ is of dimension $N \times N$.

Then **the largest eigenvalue of $A$ is equal to $\max_{i} \sum^{N}_{j=1} |A_{ij}|$.**

Is this statement true? If so, how shall I show it and does the symmetry matter here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not equal to the largest **absolute value** of eivenvalues. For a counterexample, consider a matrix $A_{11}=0, A_{12}=A_{21}=A_{22}=1$.

However, it is a bound of eigenvalues.

Let $A$ be a complex square matrix.

Then, all its eigenvalues are bounded by $min \{ max_j \sum_i |A_{ij}|, max_i \sum_j |A_{ij}|\}$. If you assume the matrix is symmetric, then the bound would be just $max_j \sum_i |A_{ij}|$.

For more information, check "Gerschgorin disk theorem" in wikipedia.

Comment: That is right, Rubertos. I was careless by missing out the "bound".